# Is it possible to sync the timing of music to airplay with local speakers?

Tags: wireless-networking, speakers

I want to buy some speakers and an airport express, or some airplay speakers and stream stuff like BBC Radio to the speakers, while also playing it on my own system. First of all, I understand I need something like airfoil. Still I worry that there will be a delay in the sound to the wireless speakers and it'll cause an echo. Is there a way to prevent that? Perhaps a way to delay my local speakers by the amount of delay the wireless speakers have?

Thanks.